# Beautifulsoup clean print and newline <br />

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html page like this;

```html
  
<li>Presence of registry value: badwindo<br/>with data: &lt;<em>system folder</em>&gt;\badwindo.exe<br/>in registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

when I try to get a clean print of this using

`match.get_text()`

I have the lines stick right after each other with no space (e.g., badwindo.exein registry key:). Also, using

`match.get_text(seprator="\n")`

I get something like this:

with data: <
system folder
>\badwindo.exe
in registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Any idea how we can get ride of < and > in correct way? I don't want to get involved in post processing and rather prefer to find out the correct way to print this.

Interestingly, when I tried to post the result the preview was showing me the correct version (the exact output that I am looking for, without < and >)! So i had to replace < with < and > with > so the output can be shown here as i am seeing here. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: FYI, you get those `<..>` in your text *because* they explicitly appear as plain text in the HTML. So it is working as designed and you need postprocessing to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this simple solution

```
html = "<li>Presence of registry ... </div>"

html = html.replace("<br>", "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want. I've compared the two methods below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = r'''
<li>Presence of registry value: badwindo<br/>with data: &lt;<em>system folder</em>&gt;\badwindo.exe<br/>in registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run</li>
</ul>
</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.li.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print (soup.get_text())
```

Result：

```
Presence of registry value: badwindowith data: &lt;system folder&gt;\badwindo.exein registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Presence of registry value: badwindowith data: <system folder>\badwindo.exein registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```